# Adopting MVVM in iOS: ViewModel responsibilities?

Tags: ios, mvvm, model, viewmodel, encapsulation

I'd like to apply the `MVVM` pattern in my next iOS project, and I have read some posts and blogs about it. But the examples they show are very simple ones with no business logic, only data model entities and `View` and `Model` updates. I am not clear who is actually the responsible for managing the business logic and operations: should it be the `ViewModel` or the `Model`?

For example, let's say that one of my features needs to:

- Ask for some data to a Web service
- Parse such data and map it to my data model entities
- Perform some checkings and operations on such entities, and update both the `View` and the `Model` with the results
- Handle a timer that triggers some more updates and operations

How should I distribute these responsibilities in order to implement `MVVM`?

Answer (score 1):

From Data Flow in MVVM we can see ViewModel responsibilities:

```
Data Flow in MVVM
1. UI calls method from ViewModel (Presenter).
2. ViewModel executes Use Case.
3. Use Case combines data from User and Repositories.
4. Each Repository returns data from a Remote Data (Network), Persistent DB Storage Source or In-memory Data (Remote or Cached).
5. Information flows back to the UI where we display the list of items.
```

More description about MVVM can here: https://tech.olx.com/clean-architecture-and-mvvm-on-ios-c9d167d9f5b3

Answer (score -2):

Let's say there is a Web service for getting comments

You can create CommentService that is responsible for downloading data, parsing and initialization/updating model. Because we need to obtain the comments, so there is a method

```
func getComments(_ completion: () -> [Comment])
```

`CommentService.getComments` is called by ViewModel in its load method.

```
class ViewModel {
  private let commentService: CommentService
  private var comments: [Comment] 
  ...

 func load() {
   commentService.getComments() { [weak self] comments in
      self?.comments = comments 
      //notify somehow the view..for example by using delegate
   }
 }
}
```

For example we want to downvote/upvote the comments, so we can implement it

```
struct CommentService {

  ...

  func upvote(comment: Comment, completion: (Void) -> (Comment)) { 

    if comment.upvoted {
       //throw error
    }
     //update via web service and update Comment's model by the response or just increment the comment.upvotes 
     //call completion with updated comment
  }  
}

struct ViewModel {

  func upvoteComment(at index:Int, completion: (() -> ())?) {
       commentService.upvote(comments[index]) { updatedComment in
          //do some more stuff with viewModel
          completion?() //in the completion is implemented updating of ui
       }
  }
}
```

The completion blocks can provide way to update ui without need of any delegate or notifications

When timer triggers the method, the end of the operation can call delegate method to update the view. Another option is to use binding framework (for example [Bond](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond)), then view can observe ViewModel properties and delegate is not needed.

https://github.com/thefuntasty/MVVMTestProject/tree/master/testMVVM
Maybe this project can help you to understand.